# Load state/data before render?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, mern

I have implemented the authentication part of my app (built using the MERN stack). The login action validates login data, then loads user data, then pushes the route to `/dashboard`. On the dashboard page, I have a simple `Welcome to the dashboard, {email}!` however I am getting an error telling me that it can not return data of null. I also have the users First & Last name as well as their email in the navbar, that also spawns an error of returning null data. I have a useEffect that loads the user data in my `App.js` but i'm still receiving the null errors.

Is there a way to load the data prior to render?

**Index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <App />
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    // check for token in LS
    if (localStorage.token) {
      setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }
    dispatch(attemptGetUser())
      .then(() => setLoading(false))
      .catch(() => setLoading(false));

    // Logout user from all tabs if they logout in another tab
    window.addEventListener('storage', () => {
      if (!localStorage.token) dispatch({ type: LOGOUT });
    });

    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  return loading ? (
    <Loading cover="page" />
  ) : (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Views} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**redux/thunks/Auth.js**

```
export const attemptLogin = (formData) => async (dispatch) => {
  await postLogin(formData)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch(login(res.data));
      dispatch(push('/dashboard'));
    })
    .then(() => {
      dispatch(attemptGetUser());
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errors = error.response.data.message;
      dispatch(setAlert('Uh-oh!', errors, 'error'));
    });
};
```

**redux/thunks/User.js**

```
export const attemptGetUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  await getUser()
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch(setUser(res.data));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errors = error.response.data.message;
      console.log(errors);
      dispatch(setAlert('Uh-oh!', errors, 'danger'));
    });
};
```

**views/app-views/dashboard**

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const { email } = useSelector((state) => state.user.user);
  return (
    <div>
      Welcome to the dashboard,
      <strong>{email}</strong>!
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

**components/layout-components/NavProfile.js**

```
export const NavProfile = () => {
  const { firstName, lastName, email } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.user.user
  );

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onLogout = () => {
    dispatch(attemptLogout());
  };

  const profileImg = '/img/avatars/thumb-1.jpg';
  const profileMenu = (
    <div className="nav-profile nav-dropdown">
      <div className="nav-profile-header">
        <div className="d-flex">
          <Avatar size={45} src={profileImg} />
          <div className="pl-3">
            <h4 className="mb-0">{firstName} {lastName}</h4>
            <span className="text-muted">{email}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="nav-profile-body">
        <Menu>
          {menuItem.map((el, i) => {
            return (
              <Menu.Item key={i}>
                <a href={el.path}>
                  <Icon className="mr-3" type={el.icon} />
                  <span className="font-weight-normal">{el.title}</span>
                </a>
              </Menu.Item>
            );
          })}
          <Menu.Item key={menuItem.legth + 1} onClick={onLogout}>
            <span>
              <LogoutOutlined className="mr-3" />
              <span className="font-weight-normal">Logout</span>
            </span>
          </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  return (
    <Dropdown placement="bottomRight" overlay={profileMenu} trigger={['click']}>
      <Menu className="d-flex align-item-center" mode="horizontal">
        <Menu.Item>
          <Avatar src={profileImg} />
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};

export default NavProfile;
```

Comment: Can you include all relevant component code? Can we see the components that are trying to render user data and have the issues/errors you report?

Comment: I've added the two components mentioned in the OP to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the error is telling you that in your redux state that `state.user.user` is undefined, this is why you can't destructure `firstName`, `lastName`, `email` values.

If in your store `state.user.user` is at least a defined, empty object (`{}`) then the access of null errors should resolve.

```
const userReducer = (state = { user: {} }, action) => {
  ...
}
```

This can still potentially leave your UI rendering "undefined", so in the component code you'll want to provide default values, i.e.

```
const { firstName = '', lastName = '', email = '' } = useSelector(
  (state) => state.user.user
);
```

The alternative is to have fully qualified initial state in your user reducer slice.

```
const initialState = {
  user: {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
  },
};

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Defining the profile fields in the initial state worked like a charm. Though i feel like there should 100% be an alternative way to render all data first then render components

Comment: @Nick Conditional rendering is usually the pattern for that, something you already do with `loading` in `App`. Sometimes within a component you may also want to display *some* loading/placeholder UI while the redux store is populating and user data isn't quite available yet.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could fix this by changing your Redux store initial state.

Taking your Dashboard component as an example:

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const { email } = useSelector((state) => state.user.user);
  return (
    <div>
      Welcome to the dashboard,
      <strong>{email}</strong>!
    </div>
  );
};
```

It expects that there is a user object with an email string in the user slice of state in your Redux store.  As [noted in their documentation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state)

You could update your `createStore` call to include a initial value for the redux store like `createStore({'user': {'user': {'email': ''}}});` for example

Comment: I would then have to do this for all the data I plan to include in the app?!?

Comment: Only for the components that don't guard against empty Redux data.  You could easily also add an `if (email !== null)` check to your component instead